# Update query returns no of column updated

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am using an `Update` query from java prepared statement. In this always update only one row at a time and I need to know that any column value is update or the number of column value is updated. Is these possible? If possible then how?

Comment: one way of going about this would be to create and then invoke a stored procedure that would return all the information you needed.

Comment: You **know** the number of columns updated because you put all columns to be updated into your `update` statement. There won't be more or less columns updated than you mention in the `set` part.

Comment: Perhaps OP wants number of rows updated to another value?

Comment: Or perhaps he wants to know number of columns updated i.e. where the original value was different then the one specified in the update statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i neeed to identify the no of column taht change its value compared with the previous value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built-in for this. You can do it with a writeable CTE, but this is not going to be very efficient:

With the following test data:

```
create table test (id integer primary key, col1 text, col2 integer, col3 date);

insert into test 
values 
(1, 'foo', 42, date '2018-02-07');
```

The following update will return `1` because only a single column changed

```
with updated as (
  update test 
     set col1 = 'x', 
         col2 = 42,
         col3 = date '2018-02-07'
  where id = 1
  returning *         
)
select (o.col1 is distinct from u.col1)::int 
       + (o.col2 is distinct from u.col2)::int 
       + (o.col3 is distinct from u.col3)::int as columns_changed
from test o
  join updated u on u.id = o.id;
```

This works because the final `select` statement of the CTE does not see the results of the `update` statement in the actual table.

If you just need to know *if* something was changed (rather than the exact number of columns) you can simplify the statement to:

```
with updated as (
  update test 
     set col1 = 'x', 
         col2 = 42,
         col3 = date '2018-02-07'
  where id = 1
  returning *         
)
select (o is distinct from u) as was_changed
from test o
  join updated u on u.id = o.id;
```

A third option is to use the [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) module:

```
with updated as (
  update test 
     set col1 = 'x', 
         col2 = 42,
         col3 = date '2018-02-07'
  where id = 1
  returning *         
)
select hstore(u) - hstore(o) as modified_columns
from test o
  join updated u on u.id = o.id;
```

would return:

```
modified_columns
----------------
"col1"=>"x"
```

Which means `col1` was update to the value `'x'`

Answer (score 0):

given:

```
t=# create table so4(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so4 values (1,'a'),(2,'b');
INSERT 0 2
```

example:

```
t=# with u as (update so4 u set i=3, t = 'c' 
from so4 w where u.i=1 and u.i = w.i 
returning (u.i <> w.i)::int  i, (u.t <> w.t)::int t) select i+t from u;
 ?column?
----------
        2
(1 row)
```

and

```
t=# with u as (update so4 u set i=3, t = 'b' 
from so4 w where u.i=2 and u.i = w.i
returning (u.i <> w.i)::int  i, (u.t <> w.t)::int t) select i+t from u;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

and

```
t=# with u as (update so4 u set i=2, t = 'b' 
from so4 w where u.i=2 and u.i = w.i 
returning (u.i <> w.i)::int  i, (u.t <> w.t)::int t) select i+t from u;
 ?column?
----------
        0
(1 row)
```

based on logic that integer value for true is 1, so you can just sum checks if old value is equal to new one.

Of course it will return no rows instead of zero when no rows updated